# Iteration causes Number Picker Listener to crash

Tags: android, iteration, numberpicker

I habve encountered a problem since I changed my Number Picker code to an 
iteration of all the Number Pickers. Up until now, an individual Number Picker worked fine - choose a number, and it was displayed in a TextView as the int 
NewVal, and even displayed in a Toast message.
But, of course, I required iteration, so that the OnValuedChangedListener 
would look out for ALL the number pickers in the xml file.
The App crashes when I try to turn a Number Picker, not before, so its obviously the Listener code - does int NewVal require iteration??
Here is my MainActivity code..

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
int newVal;
private TextView tv;

Button btnDisplay;
private CheckBox  chk1, chk2, chk3, chk7, chk8, chk9, chk10, chk11, chk12, chk13, chk14, chk15,
chk16, chk17, chk18, chk19, chk20, chk21, chk22, chk23, chk24, chk25, chk26, chk27, chk28, chk29, chk30, chk31, chk32, chk33, chk34, chk35, chk36, chk37, chk38, chk39, chk40, chk41, chk42, chk43, chk44, chk45, chk46, chk47, chk48, chk49, chk50, chk51, chk52, chk53;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

setupUI();


addListenerOnChkIos();

}

public void setupUI()
{

    int[] textViewIDs = new int[] {R.id.tvId1, R.id.tvId2, R.id.tvId3, R.id.tvId7,
            R.id.tvId8, R.id.tvId9, R.id.tvId10, R.id.tvId11, R.id.tvId12, R.id.tvId13, R.id.tvId14, R.id.tvId15, R.id.tvId16, R.id.tvId17, 
            R.id.tvId18, R.id.tvId19, R.id.tvId20, R.id.tvId21, R.id.tvId22, R.id.tvId23, R.id.tvId24, R.id.tvId25, R.id.tvId26, R.id.tvId27, R.id.tvId28, R.id.tvId29, R.id.tvId30, R.id.tvId31, 
            R.id.tvId32, R.id.tvId33, R.id.tvId34, R.id.tvId35, R.id.tvId36, R.id.tvId37, R.id.tvId38, R.id.tvId39, R.id.tvId40, R.id.tvId41, R.id.tvId42, R.id.tvId43, R.id.tvId44, R.id.tvId45, R.id.tvId46, R.id.tvId47, R.id.tvId48, R.id.tvId49, R.id.tvId50, R.id.tvId51, R.id.tvId52, R.id.tvId53};

    for(int i=0; i < textViewIDs.length; i++) {
        TextView tv = (TextView ) findViewById(textViewIDs[i]);
    }
    //tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvId1);

    int[] numpickIDs = new int[] {R.id.npId1, R.id.npId2, R.id.npId3, R.id.npId7,
            R.id.npId8, R.id.npId9, R.id.npId10, R.id.npId11, R.id.npId12, R.id.npId13, R.id.npId14, R.id.npId15, R.id.npId16, R.id.npId17, 
            R.id.npId18, R.id.npId19, R.id.npId20, R.id.npId21, R.id.npId22, R.id.npId23, R.id.npId24, R.id.npId25, R.id.npId26, R.id.npId27, R.id.npId28, R.id.npId29, R.id.npId30, R.id.npId31, 
            R.id.npId32, R.id.npId33, R.id.npId34, R.id.npId35, R.id.npId36, R.id.npId37, R.id.npId38, R.id.npId39, R.id.npId40, R.id.npId41, R.id.npId42, R.id.npId43, R.id.npId44, R.id.npId45, R.id.npId46, R.id.npId47, R.id.npId48, R.id.npId49, R.id.npId50, R.id.npId51, R.id.npId52, R.id.npId53};

    for(int j=0; j < numpickIDs.length; j++) {
        NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker ) findViewById(numpickIDs[j]);


    //NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.npId1);

    np.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener()
    {
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, 
            int newVal)
        {
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(newVal)); 
        }        
    });

    np.setMaxValue(12);
    np.setMinValue(0);
    }

}

public void addListenerOnChkIos() {

    chk1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk1);
    chk2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk2);
    chk3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk3);
    chk7 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk7);
    chk8 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk8);
    chk9 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk9);
    chk10 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk10);
    chk11 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk11);
    chk12 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk12);
    chk13 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk13);
    chk14 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk14);
    chk15 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk15);
    chk16 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk16);
    chk17 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk17);
    chk18 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk18);
    chk19 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk19);
    chk20 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk20);
    chk21 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk21);
    chk22 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk22);
    chk23 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk23);
    chk24 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk24);
    chk25 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk25);
    chk26 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk26);
    chk27 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk27);
    chk28 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk28);
    chk29 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk29);
    chk30 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk30);
    chk31 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk31);
    chk32 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk32);
    chk33 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk33);
    chk34 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk34);
    chk35 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk35);
    chk36 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk36);
    chk37 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk37);
    chk38 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk38);
    chk39 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk39);
    chk40 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk40);
    chk41 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk41);
    chk42 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk42);
    chk43 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk43);
    chk44 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk44);
    chk45 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk45);
    chk46 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk46);
    chk47 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk47);
    chk48 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk48);
    chk49 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk49);
    chk50 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk50);
    chk51 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk51);
    chk52 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk52);
    chk53 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk53);








    btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);

    btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    //chk1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
          //Run when button is clicked
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

        //StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        //result.append("Haddock-Large : ").append(chk1.isChecked());
        //result.append("\nHaddock-Medium : ").append(chk2.isChecked());
        //result.append("\nHaddock-Small :").append(chk3.isChecked());
        //result.append("\nKids Corner : ").append(chk4.isChecked());


        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, tv.getText().toString() + " " + result.toString(),
                //Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         // if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, tv.getText().toString() + " " + "Haddock Large",
                //Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          //}
      //}
    //});

          int totalamount=0;  
          StringBuilder result=new StringBuilder();  
          result.append("Selected Items:\n");  
          if(chk1.isChecked()){  
              result.append(tv.getText().toString() + "x" + "Haddock(Large) 100Rs");  
              totalamount+=100;  
          }  
          if(chk2.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nHaddock(Med) 50Rs");  
              totalamount+=50;  

          }  
          if(chk3.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nHaddock(Small) 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          } 
          if(chk7.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nChips 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk8.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nCone of Chips 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk9.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nChip Butty 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk10.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nFries 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk11.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nPattie 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk12.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nPattie Buttie 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk13.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nFish Cake 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk14.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nBreadcakes 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk15.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nHam Fritter 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk16.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nCorned Beef Fritter 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk17.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nFish Fritter 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk18.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nBeef Burger 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk19.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nSmall Sausage 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk20.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nJumbo Sausage 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk21.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nPickled Eggs 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk22.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nPickled Onions 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk23.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\n8 Onion Rings 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk24.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nScampi(8) & chips/fries 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk25.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nPattie Bitesx8 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk26.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nHotdog"
                    + " 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk27.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nHotdog w/chip/fries and a can 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk28.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nHome Made Fish Cakes 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk29.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nCod Roe 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk30.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\n4 Fish Strips 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk31.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nChicken & Mushroom 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk32.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nSteak & Kidney 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk33.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nBeef & Onion 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk34.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\n1/4lb Beef Burger 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk35.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\n1/2lb Beef Burger  120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk36.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\n1/4ib Cheese Burger 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk37.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\n1/2lb Cheese Burger 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk38.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nChicken Burger 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk39.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nDouble Chicken Burger 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk40.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nPot of Peas 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk41.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nChips spice tub 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk42.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nSalt 250g 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk43.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nVinegar 284ml 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk44.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nTomato Sauce 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk45.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nCans 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk46.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nKids Cup Drinks 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk47.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nBottled Water 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk48.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\n2ltr Bottles star 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }if(chk49.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\n 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk50.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nBurger 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk51.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nBurger 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk52.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nBurger 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }
          if(chk53.isChecked()){  
              result.append("\nBurger 120Rs");  
              totalamount+=120;  
          }

          result.append("\nTotal: "+totalamount+"Rs");  
          //Displaying the message on the toast  
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
      }  

  });  
}



}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your listener the textView tv you are reffering to is just null, it's your class member never initialized.

edit : regarding your additional question

> Now the App doesn't crash, I notice that ONLY the LAST number picker works OK ie npId53 - so why is it only selecting the LAST number picker in the iteration, and not npId1, npId2, tvId1, tvId2 and so on, in the Listerner??

=> Because you only store one textview and it's the last one of your loop.

Try something like this :

```
private TextView[] tvs;
public void setupUI()
{

int[] textViewIDs = new int[] {R.id.tvId1, R.id.tvId2, R.id.tvId3, R.id.tvId7,
        R.id.tvId8, R.id.tvId9, R.id.tvId10, R.id.tvId11, R.id.tvId12, R.id.tvId13, R.id.tvId14, R.id.tvId15, R.id.tvId16, R.id.tvId17, 
        R.id.tvId18, R.id.tvId19, R.id.tvId20, R.id.tvId21, R.id.tvId22, R.id.tvId23, R.id.tvId24, R.id.tvId25, R.id.tvId26, R.id.tvId27, R.id.tvId28, R.id.tvId29, R.id.tvId30, R.id.tvId31, 
        R.id.tvId32, R.id.tvId33, R.id.tvId34, R.id.tvId35, R.id.tvId36, R.id.tvId37, R.id.tvId38, R.id.tvId39, R.id.tvId40, R.id.tvId41, R.id.tvId42, R.id.tvId43, R.id.tvId44, R.id.tvId45, R.id.tvId46, R.id.tvId47, R.id.tvId48, R.id.tvId49, R.id.tvId50, R.id.tvId51, R.id.tvId52, R.id.tvId53};

tvs = new TextView[53];
for(int i=0; i < textViewIDs.length; i++) {
    TextView tv = (TextView ) findViewById(textViewIDs[i]);
    tvs[i] = tv;
}
//tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvId1);

int[] numpickIDs = new int[] {R.id.npId1, R.id.npId2, R.id.npId3, R.id.npId7,
        R.id.npId8, R.id.npId9, R.id.npId10, R.id.npId11, R.id.npId12, R.id.npId13, R.id.npId14, R.id.npId15, R.id.npId16, R.id.npId17, 
        R.id.npId18, R.id.npId19, R.id.npId20, R.id.npId21, R.id.npId22, R.id.npId23, R.id.npId24, R.id.npId25, R.id.npId26, R.id.npId27, R.id.npId28, R.id.npId29, R.id.npId30, R.id.npId31, 
        R.id.npId32, R.id.npId33, R.id.npId34, R.id.npId35, R.id.npId36, R.id.npId37, R.id.npId38, R.id.npId39, R.id.npId40, R.id.npId41, R.id.npId42, R.id.npId43, R.id.npId44, R.id.npId45, R.id.npId46, R.id.npId47, R.id.npId48, R.id.npId49, R.id.npId50, R.id.npId51, R.id.npId52, R.id.npId53};

for(int j=0; j < numpickIDs.length; j++) {
    NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker ) findViewById(numpickIDs[j]);


final index = j;
//NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.npId1);

np.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener()
{
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, 
        int newVal)
    {
        tvs[index].setText(String.valueOf(newVal)); 
    }        
});

np.setMaxValue(12);
np.setMinValue(0);
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry - I don;t understand. What should I change in the code?? Thx.

Comment: I used TextView tv on a single tv testview, and it worked fine - it was the addition of the iteration which caused the crash in the Listener..

Comment: I have since removed the TextView from the front of TextView tv = (TextView ) findViewById(textViewIDs[i]); - the App doesn't crash any longer - BUT choice of number in Number Pickers is no longer showing up in the tv TextView! Anyone any ideas??

Comment: Now the App doesn't crash, I notice that ONLY the LAST number picker works OK ie npId53 - so why is it only selecting the LAST number picker in the iteration, and not npId1, npId2, tvId1, tvId2 and so on, in the Listerner??

Comment: Basically because you're not in the same loop than the one you used to find your textviews and only kept one reference (on the last one in the loop). I edited my post with one suggestion.

Comment: Hi again! Many, many thanks! But one problem - the tvs[i] inside the Listener shows as an error - i can't be resolved to a variable. Does it need a new loop of its own?? Thanks again for your great assistance!